# cannot find symbol MODULE$

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to access Scala `object` that is nested in Scala `class`

```
class ObjectState {

  object Mirror {
    def inMirrorObjectState(state: ObjectState): Unit = {
      ...
    }
}
```

I am doing it like this

```
import com.lapots.game.journey.osm.domain.ObjectState;
public class StaticInterop {

    public static void readObjectState(ObjectState objState) {
        ObjectState.Mirror$.MODULE$.inMirrorObjectState(objState);
    }

}
```

But it fails during compilation

```
error: cannot find symbol
    ObjectState.Mirror$.MODULE$.inMirrorObjectState(objState);
                       ^
symbol:   variable MODULE$
location: class ObjectState.Mirror$
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that doesn't work is because an object inside a class is not actually a singleton. Each instance of ObjectState gets its own object.

To access that singleton you'd have to do this:

```
ObjectState a = new ObjectState();
//use the above instance to access the singleton inside it
a.Mirror().inMirrorObjectState(state);
```

If you want a true singleton inner class, you can change the outer class to an object as well:

```
object ObjectState {

  object Mirror {
    def inMirrorObjectState(state: ObjectState): Unit = {
      ...
    }
}
```

and then it would work like this:

```
ObjectState.Mirror$.MODULE$.inMirrorObjectState(state);
```

Comment: Does not work `public static void readObjectState(ObjectState objState) {
            objState.Mirror().inMirrorObjectState(objState);
        }`

Comment: woops. No. My bad. It is just IDE cannot resolve `Mirror`. It actually works.